# No Gallery app on Lenovo K6 Power

Tags: gallery, lenovo

I bought a Lenovo K6 Power mobile, but it's not showing the gallery in the menu and storage.

I have done all the basic steps, but I don't see the Gallery app.

What can I do to fix this issue?

Comment: I'm also a user of same device. You need to install your own gallery app or you can use Google photos

Answer (score 1):

Recent models of Lenovo K-series are running on PURE UI, which is similar to/the same as stock Android experience, thus Lenovo did not preinstall their own Lenovo Gallery app. Some models have Google Photos preinstalled as their stock gallery app instead. Otherwise, users have to install any compatible 3rd-party Gallery app on their own.

References from Lenovo Forums:

- Lenovo Vibe K5 Note: [No in-built/(in the phone) gallery app in Lenovo Vibe K5 Note](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/K-and-Vibe-Z-Series-Smartphones/No-in-built-in-the-phone-gallery-app-in-Lenovo-Vibe-K5-Note/m-p/3388854)
- Lenovo Vibe K5 Note: [Gallery app not present in vibe k5 note](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/K-and-Vibe-Z-Series-Smartphones/Gallery-app-not-present-in-vibe-k5-note/m-p/3398956)
- Lenovo K6 Power: [Lenovo K6 Power Gallery App is Not Showing](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/K-and-Vibe-Z-Series-Smartphones/Lenovo-K6-Power-Gallery-App-is-Not-Showing/m-p/3507199)
- Lenovo K6 Note: [K6 note has no gallery](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/K-and-Vibe-Z-Series-Smartphones/K6-note-has-no-gallery/m-p/3570651)
- Lenovo K8 Note: [Lenovo Gallery App Missing](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/K8-XT1902-Smartphones/Lenovo-Gallery-App-Missing/m-p/3778279)
- Lenovo K8 Note: [Not able to see gallery](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/K8-XT1902-Smartphones/Not-able-to-see-gallery/m-p/3926032)

Answer (score 0):

Flash your device with its **stock ROM (firmware)** and any problems that might have caused the *damage* can be fixed.. if not, they might not have provided any gallery for your ROM/device

Comment: Sir i can't understand you. Please tell what i do.